# Having a weird issue with Spring-boot + Rest Controller + Post Request + Kotlin + Unit testing

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

### The build file

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.3.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    id("com.google.cloud.tools.jib") version "2.5.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.0"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.0"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.4.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("com.h2database:h2:1.4.200")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "14"
    }
}
```

### The controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/notification")
class NotificationResource(
    private val jobService: JobService
) {
    @PostMapping("/enqueue-mobile", produces = [APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE], consumes = [APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    @ResponseStatus(ACCEPTED)
    fun enqueueMobile(@Valid @RequestBody mobile: Mobile): List<Job> = jobService.create(mobile)

    @GetMapping("/job-status/{id}", produces = [APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    @ResponseStatus(OK)
    fun jobStatus(@Valid @PathVariable id: UUID): Job = jobService.fetch(id).get()
}

data class Mobile(
    val ids: List<Long>,
    val message: String
)
```

### Unit testing file

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class NotificationResourceMobileTests {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @Test
    fun `with correct payload having one mobile id in a list and message - request returns http ok and response`() {
        val mobile = Mobile(ids = listOf<Long>(100, 101, 102), message = "test")
        mockMvc.perform(post(urlPath).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).content(mobile.asJsonString()))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isAccepted)
    }

    companion object {
        const val urlPath = "/notification/enqueue-mobile"
    }
}
```

### The Request

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /notification/enqueue-mobile
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"38"]
             Body = {"ids":[100,101,102],"message":"test"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.notification.resource.NotificationResource
           Method = com.notification.resource.NotificationResource#enqueueMobile(Mobile)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"timestamp":"2020-09-04T23:51:49.609645","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"'java.util.List com.notification.resource.Mobile.getIds()'","trace":"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List com.notification.resource.Mobile.getIds()'\n\tat com.notification.service.JobService$create$1.invoke(JobService.kt:29)\n\tat com.notification.service.JobService$create$1.invoke(JobService.kt:19)\n\tat com.notification.resource.NotificationResource.enqueueMobile(NotificationResource.kt:25)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\n\tat org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)\n\tat org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)\n\tat org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:183)\n\tat com.notification.resource.NotificationResourceMobileTests.with correct payload having one mobile id in a list and message - request returns http ok and response(NotificationResourceMobileTests.kt:134)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)\n\tat org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)\n\tat org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)\n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)\n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)\n\tat org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)\n\tat org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)\n\tat org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)\n\tat org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)\n\tat org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)\n\tat org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)\n","path":"uri=/notification/enqueue-mobile"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /notification/enqueue-mobile
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"38"]
             Body = {"ids":[100,101,102],"message":"test"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.notification.resource.NotificationResource
           Method = com.notification.resource.NotificationResource#enqueueMobile(Mobile)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"timestamp":"2020-09-04T23:51:49.609645","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"'java.util.List com.notification.resource.Mobile.getIds()'","path":"uri=/notification/enqueue-mobile"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

Status expected:<202> but was:<400>
Expected :202
Actual   :400
```

> Why do I get NoSuchMethodError - when I have the field in the `data class`. Note: I can test the feature after running the app and using Postman. The same fails in unit-testing.
> The unit-testing with `mockmvc` is not working as expected. The same works fine for `get` methods. Any input?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List com.notification.resource.Mobile.getIds()'
    at com.notification.service.JobService$create$1.invoke(JobService.kt:29)
    at com.notification.service.JobService$create$1.invoke(JobService.kt:19)
    at com.notification.resource.NotificationResource.enqueueMobile(NotificationResource.kt:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: You can see the full error trace here. https://gist.github.com/gpuliyar/3b700dafe6947deb081ece5b4d8cc028

Comment: Show `JobService.create`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - this is how the `jobservice.create` looks like - https://gist.github.com/gpuliyar/e2eab7896e6259f6ec236992b1736f0c

Comment: Never mind. Fixed the issue. Moved the data class to a separate package. It is weird that the functionality just worked fine while testing using postman when the data class was in the same file as the controller resource but the unit tests failed.